# how to post the data in the format [{Secid=2, Answer=3, QID=4596}, {Answer=4, QID=4593},{Answer=4, QID=4592}] from android application to web api

Tags: android, post, hashmap

I am developing an online examination app which have different sections like aptitude,reasoning etc.I have to post the section id , question id and answer until the loop iterate to last section .Here is my code.

```
      if (count==0)
        {
          HashMap<String,String> answers= new HashMap<>();
          answers.put("Secid",secid);
          answers.put("QID",Questionid);
          answers.put("Answer",Ind);
          MyAnswerlist.add(answers);
        }
       else 
       {
       HashMap<String,String> answers= new HashMap<>();
       answers.put("QID",Questionid);
       answers.put("Answer",Ind);
       MyAnswerlist.add(answers);
       }
```

Suggest me which is the best suitable post method for my problem.

Comment: You can use JSON to POST to webservice

Comment: i am new to android.help me how to post using json